# Getting a Dictionary from a Query with GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

Given two persisted entities

```
public class Header
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Detail> Details { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Detail
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Header MyHeader { get; set; }

    public virtual string Text { get; set; }

    public virtual object LotsOfPropertiesIDontNeed { get; set; }
}
```

I want to populate a new object

```
public class MiniHeader
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<int, string> DetailTexts { get; set; }
}
```

with only the name from the Header, and with a dictionary relating detail IDs to the associated texts.  Note that `Detail` also has `LotsOfPropertiesIDontNeed`, which I would prefer not to pull 
across the wire or even request from SQL Server.

With the code

```
IEnumerable<MiniHeader> mini =
    ctx.Details.Include(d => d.MyHeader)
    .GroupBy(d => d.MyHeader)
    .Select(g => new MiniHeader()
    {
        Name = g.Key.Name,
        DetailTexts = g.ToDictionary(d => d.Id, d => d.Text)
    });
```

I get the expected

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,System.String]

since .ToDictionary cannot execute on the database side.  I can make it work like this:

```
IEnumerable<MiniHeader> mini =
    ctx.Details.Include(d => d.MyHeader)
    .GroupBy(d => d.MyHeader)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(g => new MiniHeader()
    {
        Name = g.Key.Name,
        DetailTexts = g.ToDictionary(d => d.Id, d => d.Text)
    });
```

but I presume that `LotsOfPropertiesIDontNeed` will be requested of SQL Server and pulled across the wire.

Is there a way to make this work, without pulling the unnecessary fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can project your results to an anonymous type and then apply `AsEnumerable` and later project to your class like:

```
IEnumerable<MiniHeader> mini =
    ctx.Details.Include(d => d.MyHeader)
    .GroupBy(d => d.MyHeader)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Name = g.Key.Name,
        Details = g.Select(i => new { i.Id, i.Text }),
    })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(e => new MiniHeader()
    {
        Name = e.Name,
        DetailTexts = e.Details.ToDictionary(d => d.Id, d => d.Text)
    });
```

This will let you get only those field that you need and later you can use `ToDictionary` on an in-memory collection.